# New to VB programming and need some advice

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a program that takes data from an access file, and then I can hit a button and create a label in a text file for it. Right now, if I hit the button to create a label for more then one, it only shows the last one which is selected. I think, I need a loop for all the `outfile.write's`, I'm just not sure what loop to use. It is not giving me any errors or anything, it just isn't printing more then one label into this text file. Also, how do I put spaces between for instance the persons first and last name since that is on the same line? This is my code so far.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmAccess
    Dim outFile As StreamWriter

    Private Sub TblMemberBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TblMemberBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblMemberBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.GolfDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GolfDataSet.tblMember' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblMemberTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GolfDataSet.tblMember)



    End Sub


    Private Sub cmdCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCreate.Click
        Dim outFile As StreamWriter
        outFile = File.CreateText("Labels.txt")

        outFile.WriteLine()
        outFile.WriteLine()
        outFile.Write(lblFirst.Text, " ")
        outFile.WriteLine(lblLast.Text)
        outFile.WriteLine(lblAddress.Text, " ")
        outFile.Write(lblCity.Text, ", ")
        outFile.Write(lblState.Text, " ")
        outFile.Write(lblZip.Text)
        outFile.WriteLine()
        outFile.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click

        Me.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

For example, my text file should look like (xxx= blank lines):

xxxx

xxxxx

Bob Smith

123 Fix Road

Tampa, Florida 12345

xxxxxx

xxxxxx

xxxxxx

Jane Doe

987 help Lane

Denver, Colorado 56789

xxxxx

xxxxx

So instead of my text file showing both labels, it would only show Jane Doe's label.

Comment: do you want add all the lable text in a textfile?

Comment: Yes. It is suppose to show a label that would be what you would put on an envelope to send to someone. But it is suppose to show more then one if I hit the create button more then once. And right now it only shows the information of the last time I hit the create button instead of all of them.

Comment: Are you getting correct reslut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following

```
Private Sub cmdCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCreate.Click
    Dim outFile As StreamWriter
    outFile = File.CreateText("Labels.txt")

    outFile.WriteLine()
    outFile.WriteLine()
    outFile.Write(lblFirst.Text & " ")
    outFile.WriteLine(lblLast.Text)
    outFile.WriteLine(lblAddress.Text & " ")
    outFile.Write(lblCity.Text & " " & ", ")
    outFile.Write(lblState.Text & " ")
    outFile.Write(lblZip.Text)
    outFile.WriteLine()
    outFile.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For space you can use the Strings.Space(numOfSpaces) method maybe it can be attached to the firstname variable before writing to file.
As for the original question i dont get what exactly u're asking for buddy...can u rephrase? also hope u didnt bind any textboxes

Comment: I typed out an example of what my text file should look like, but instead of showing more then one "label" it is only showing the last one.

Comment: so even if u want to display the first record it is displaying the last one only right??

Comment: The way u write to this text file will give u problems when retrieving...from my view. Can u try writing one record in one line and using a delimiter such as a # or $ or , or * and then when retrieving u can store once record in an array as one whole string put together but to retrieve maybe first name only u use the delimiter to show where one column(for that record ie a tuple) ends.

Comment: eg to write a record right...it looks something like dim city as String = "London"  dim country as string ="Britain"  outFile.writeline(city &"#" &country) now to access it use the split function but an array should be declared first dim cityName() as string cityName = inFile.Readline.Split("#"c) actually this reads only one record per line such that cityName(0) would be London and cityName(1) would be Britain but if u are good with VB a 2d array might solve this just never tried it before...moved away from textfiles years ago!! they are problems

Comment: Yes that is right, but I have no idea what you are talking about with the array. I've really only been programming in Vb for a couple weeks, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: or maybe using your mathematical knowledge u can count the rows and specify which rows to take (discarding the blank spaces and taking 3lines after that)...gosh i will try this when i get back from church bra im running late. add two spaces after each record for your loop to work i see u've shown 2empty rows then 3...just make it 2 or 3...not both

Comment: how are u retrieving the records? do u search using a keyword or u wna press a button and then the next record shows?

Comment: I am getting it through an access database, and when I put them into my form, VB automatically writes the code for it, so there is a button to click from one record to another.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for displaying all name and address details

```
Private Sub cmdCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCreate.Click

 Dim outFile As StreamWriter
        If File.Exists("D:\sathish\Labels.txt") Then
            outFile = New StreamWriter("Labels.txt", True)
        Else
            outFile = New StreamWriter("Labels.txt")
        End If


        outFile.WriteLine()
    outFile.WriteLine()
    outFile.Write(lblFirst.Text & " ")
    outFile.WriteLine(lblLast.Text)
    outFile.WriteLine(lblAddress.Text & " ")
    outFile.Write(lblCity.Text & " " & ", ")
    outFile.Write(lblState.Text & " ")
    outFile.Write(lblZip.Text)
    outFile.WriteLine()
    outFile.Close()

End Sub
```